# OData aggregate column subquery

Tags: c#, subquery, odata, aggregate-functions

I have a requirement to query an OData endpoint to return rows grouped by Status with aggregate functions on column data. For example to return the total of all invoices where the payments to date are less than 100 and also to return the total of all invoices where the payments to date are less than 500.

My data model has the following fields (C# model exposed via an OData API).

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public string InvoiceType {get; set;}
    public decimal InvoicePayments {get; set;}
    public decimal EligibleValue {get; set;}
}
```

I can get the data I need at the SQL query level by performing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [i].[Status], 
    COUNT(*) AS [Count], 
    (SELECT SUM(t.val) FROM (SELECT InvoicePurchaseValue as val FROM Invoice WHERE InvoicePayments < 100) t) AS ValueLessThan100, 
    (SELECT SUM(t.val) FROM (SELECT InvoicePurchaseValue as val FROM Invoice WHERE InvoicePayments < 500) t) AS ValueLessThan500
FROM [Invoice] AS [i]
GROUP BY [i].[Status]
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this with a single OData query.

I've got as far as

```
http://<myserver>/odata/Invoice?$apply=groupby((Status),aggregate(InvoicePurchaseValue with sum as ValueLessThan100, InvoicePurchaseValue with sum as ValueLessThan500))
```

However I can't figure out how to perform the subquery on each of the columns.